# Task - Sending Email using email field of a custom object

Tags: visualforce

Is it possible to send Email (in Task panel) using email field of a my custom object (Candidate__c)?

Currently it will only allow to use a Contact's email.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You will need to build a custom button for that. You could use the method in the link below to populate the email field with your custom email field.

http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html

Comment: This is the primary reason why people are encouraged to use Record Types on contacts, accounts, and leads, instead of creating custom "people-like" objects; there is a ton of missing functionality you have to build yourself if you ignore that principle.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the email you need to send to as a string with SOQL (*emailIwantToUse*) and then use it in the URL with the **"p24"** parameter that controls the "additional to" field.

I.e. https://eu5.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p24=email@agent.com

Following an example:
 `return new PageReference('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?rtype=003&p24=' + emailIwantToUse + '&p3_lkid=' + IdOfTheObject + '&retURL=' + pageToRefer + '&p5=&template_id=' + templateXXX.Id + '');` 
If you have no idea what I'm talking about, check the link (http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html) given by PepeFloyd about the URL Hacking method.